# Error when ISO 8601 date/time sent over HTTP and created in to PHP DateTime object

Tags: php, datetime, iso8601

I have an ISO 8601 compliant date/time string `2014-12-11T23:43:44+00:00` which I’m passing over HTTP to a web server. There, I pull the data from my HTTP POST field and everything’s great, when I print_r my parameters, the value is returned as `2014-12-11T23:43:44 00:00`.

What I notice though, is that the `+` is now missing, (I’m guessing this is in the presentation of the data rather than what the data is encoded as and isn’t(?) a problem, right?)

Then, on parsing the value as a parameter to create a new DateTime object, I get the following error:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2014-12-11T23:43:44 00:00) at position 20 (0): Double time specification
```

I’m guessing this is because it sees the appending `00:00` as another time after the `23:43:44`, when of course this is the time difference.

Is this because the `+` is missing or am I doing something else wrong?

I should also point out that my original value (`2014-12-11T23:43:44+00:00`) comes from http://www.timestampgenerator.com's ISO 8601 field.

***Edit:***

Here’s the code I use to get the string from the POST request in PHP:

```
static function request_parameters($including_request_uri = false)
{
    $request_parameters = $_REQUEST;

    if (!$including_request_uri)
    {
        unset($request_parameters[PARAMETER_NAME_REQUEST]);
    }

    return $request_parameters;
}
```

Then I retrieve the value like this:

```
$parameters =       RESTController::request_parameters();
$date_created =     $parameters[UNIVERSALLY_UNIQUE_OBJECT_KEY_DATE_CREATED];
```

Comment: Are you sure it's POST? `+` is one form of representing a space in a URL, so this would be easily explained if we were talking about GET.

Comment: to be expected. `+` in a URL is an encoded space char. Your date string is being run through url_decode() somewhere, and the `+` gets decoded to a space. If you want to pass that `+` through a query string, it'll have be encoded to `%2B`

Comment: try with $date = preg_replace("/ /","+",$date);

Comment: See edit for how I get the POST data. No `url_decode()` is being sent

Comment: I know this sounds silly but ensure that you trim the string to remove any whitespace characters. This is such a guess as the data looks fine fron the website.

Comment: @RyanVincent No luck after trimming the string.

Comment: Display the returned value, in the $_POST field, in hex and check that plus sign is actually there. If it is then look at the processing after that point. should be 0x2b

Comment: Look at the answer by @ehime, the `+` turns out to be missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always try doing `trim(' ', str_replace(' ','+',$datetime));` to test. This will both strip whitespace on the outside and turn your inner space with an ISO8901 compliant time.

I believe your POST coming in is being interpreted as as an encoded space. Another way to do it (if you have control over whatever is sending is) POST with:

```
$datetime = urlencode($datetime);
```

Then on the receiving end:

```
$datetime = urldecode($_POST['datetime']);
```

Comment: This seems to work, I can’t help but feel it’s a quick fix/workaround though. Is this the right way to fix this issue?

Comment: This is a work around, do you have control of whatever is posting this? If so, I would highly recommend urlencoding (like above) before sending, that would be a real fix not a patch as you are escaping, not sidestepping. ;)

Comment: Yeah I have control on both ends. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Just one caveat though, `urldecode()` isn’t needed on the receiving end for some reason. Not sure why, makes me think maybe the string is being decoded somewhere (despite the fact that as seen in the edit to my question it isn’t/shouldn’t)

Comment: Also, just a note to anyone, it’s `urlencode()` and `urldecode()` in PHP. (Not sure why I thought there was an `_` either)

Comment: Altered my answer to reflect that, yeah some use snake case some don't. Gets hard to remember after awhile